# How to add our own group in Excel Options?

Tags: c#-4.0, excel-2010

For my project i wanted to add my own group(like General,Proofing, Formulas) in Excel->Options where i would display all the options related to my project like Logging options etc... I tried using backstage view but i am not able to edit this dialog using that.

Could someone help me out with this?

Regards,
Adith

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong), you can't change the options in `Excel --> Options`. The best you can do (as you mentioned before) is to modify the `Backstage View`. [This website has an incredible Backstage View editing tutorial](http://www.rondebruin.nl/backstage.htm).

I took the code in their **Add custom Tab to Backstage view** section and used it to modify a workbook to show you what the output looks like. After modifying, my workbook opens with the new tab `MyTab` and a bunch of new groupings and options:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sam. Ya i tried playing with the backstage and most probably will do something like what is shown above.

Comment: Glad to help. Best of luck with the rest of your project.